# Add view dynamically to the right bottom corner

Tags: android, dynamic, view

I have a relative layout defined in xml that I populate dynamically with ImageView. I put new ImageView to right of the last one.
However, when too many ImageView have been added, the width of the screen is too small to display all of them. So, I'm looking for a way to add these ImageView below if there is no room left on the line...

Please tell me if I'm not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a [gridview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use set the scaleType of images to make them scale or use another layouts, grid or depending on the visual requirements also gallery (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html).